# Returning a Random Position and Color With SASS

Tags: sass

I'm trying to create a random color and position for drop shadows with SASS.  So far I have found help and got the positioning working, but am currently struggling with the random color.  My code is as follows:

```
@import compass

@function multiple-box-shadow ($n, $sc) 
  $value: '#{random(2000)}px #{random(2000)}px $sc'
  @for $i from 2 through $n
    $value: '#{$value} , #{random(2000)}px #{random(2000)}px $sc'

  @return unquote($value)
  @return unquote($sc)

$shadows-small:  multiple-box-shadow(700, '#0000ff')
$shadows-medium: multiple-box-shadow(200, '#00ff00')
$shadows-big:    multiple-box-shadow(100, '#ff0000')
```

[Link to forked Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGgjaj)

Comment: https://pankajparashar.com/posts/random-colors-sass

Comment: Why are you asking about returning a random position when you're already doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
rgb(random(256)-1, random(256)-1, random(256)-1);
```